# Why ng-click not working on custom directive template?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I want to create a drop down filter in my project. So, I created the drop down list using directive, in which the list contains ng-click event in the template. I don't know where I was wrong. Kindly, provide solution. Thanks in Advance.

My HTML file

```
<div ng-controller="drop">
 <a ng-click="toggleList">Select</a>

 <div ng-if="toggleDrop">
 <drop-down></drop-down>
 </div>
</div>
```

My Controller Code

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('drop', ['$scope', function($scope){
     $scope.toggleDrop = false;
     $scope.filterList = ['One','Two','Three'];
     $scope.toggleList = function() {
           $scope.toggleDrop = !$scope.toggleDrop;
     }

     $scope.filterContent = function() {
          alert('dfdf')
     }

}]);
```

My Directive Code

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
      .directive('dropDown', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'drop.html'
    controller: drop
  }
});
```

My Directive Template File

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="items in filterList" ng-click="filterContent()">{{items}}</li>
</ul>
```

Everything works fine except the ng-click behaviour. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few issues with your code,

(i) Your directive should not have a new module with empty dependencies, change it as,

```
angular.module('myApp')
      .directive('dropDown', function()
```

(ii) You are missing a comma after the controller inside directive,

```
angular.module('myApp')
      .directive('dropDown', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'drop.html',
    controller: 'drop'
  }
});
```

(iii)Should be **`toggleList()`** which is a function,

```
 <a ng-click="toggleList()">Select</a>
```

**[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/Sboo72Ipw5H6JdrxGwtu?p=preview)**

Comment: Also in the directive use single quotes when assigning the controller `controller: 'drop'`

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka I don't think so `drop` controller should be used inside directive. As it has been already used in parent controller.. Either we should make directive controller code specific to `drop-down` directive code. Or we can share parent controller code without specifying controller

Comment: @PankajParkar yeah, but adding it won't be an issue too

Comment: @Sajeetharan I understand. My point was unnecessarily `drop` controller instance will be created twice. which I'll never prefer

Comment: @PankajParkar In this scenario you are right. But if we ever use the directive outside of its parent controller, then we need to add it.

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka that is what I said in my first comment

Comment: Then it's better to make directive controller specific to that directive.

Comment: @Sajeetharan thanks for your work...Your code works for me..but when i add the following line of code in filterContent method, It doesn't affect the view.

"$scope.toggleDrop = false;"

This line should hide the list, but it doesn't. Thank s in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing parenthesis to call function on `ng-click`

```
ng-click="toggleList()"
```

Also in directive code don't declare angular module once again. If you that it will wipe out old registered component from that module. Use `angular.module('moduleName')`(that will return create module) while registering new component to module

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
```

should be

```
//module getter
angular.module('myApp')
```

Additionally directive has wrong DDO, correct it to below

```
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'drop.html', //added `,` here
    //I don't think so you need controller here as you shared the parent controller
    //wrap with `'` but it will create `drop` controller instance inside directive again
    //controller: 'drop'  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have given the function name 'toggleList' but you have not called the function. It should work when you call the function as follows:

```
 <a ng-click="toggleList()">Select</a>
```

You are missing parenthesis in the function.

Thanks